# Uninstalled unmanaged package

Tags: unmanaged-package

I've uninstalled unmanaged package in my org accidentaly. 
I've to retrive that packages with datas. Please help me on this

Comment: Same Question asked here.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/how-to-restore-a-deleted-unmanaged-apex-class

Answer (score 4):

before uninstalling the package three options are available

[image]

Which option you have selected before uninstalling the package?
If you have saved the copy then you can get it back before 48 Hrs! Options are self explanatory.

GoTo >> Installed Packages >> Check Uninstalled Packages Section 
You will find your uninstalled package.
[image]

Click on Data you will get a Zip file containing your data.

Comment: I've checked Save a copy of this package's data for 48 hours after uninstall

Comment: Data button is not visible for me

Comment: I've got a mail my app is successfully uninstalled

Comment: Could you Please share the screenshot!